# How to open file compare version window in maximize mode in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am using TFS 2010 and visual studio 2010

When I compare version local and latest version of the file then window open in a small size so each time I want to maximize mode.

so can anyone tell me is there any settings for that?

Comment: This has to be one of the lowest risk, highest return UI tweaks that the diff tool sorely needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other alternatives to the standard compare tool that would give you more options.

Here is a good post on changing the diff/merge tool to winmerge.
http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/

Here is another tool that replaces the diff/merge tool
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dace3633-0b51-4629-85d4-c59cdce5bb3b/

Lastly, the compare/diff experience in Visual Studio 2012 has been completely rewritten and now is a document window with intellisense.  Best of all you can open Visual Studio 2010 (sp1) projects in Visual Studio 2012 without converting the solution/projects.

Comment: but I don't want to use third party tool.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this with the default diffmerge.exe application.  I checked online, in the registry, and the command line options.  The only way to do this is with a custom tool.